# Next.js Link Component Prevent default action

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Working with Next.js and I have a Link component displayed as a button however I want a user only to be able to navigate to /login if some condition is met (they are verified). Currently the handleClick function is being called and is returning false, as it should, however the app navigates regardless.

What am I doing wrong?

Running next.js V 7.0.2

Many many thanks.

```
  <Link href="/login"> 
  <button onClick={() => {handleClick(event)}}>Buyer</button> 
  </Link>

  function handleClick(event)
  {
     if(verified == false)
     {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
     }
     else
     {
         return true;
     }
  }
```

Comment: I think you want to move your button out of the Link component and inside the handleClick event use the history API to push to login. The reason why you would move it out is because Link component is doing the routing to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to my comment, I just had a look at the docs for next.js and it gives an example of a DOM element and a click event that changes to another page. https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#imperatively

By the looks of the things you will want to import Router and then add `Router.push('/login')` like:

```
    function handleClick(event)
  {
     if(verified) {
         Router.push('/login')
     }
  }
```